# Jest moduleNameMapper not working - error TS2307: Cannot find module '@/[...]'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, jestjs

I have an issue with my Jest test suites not running because they are not importing correctly. I have set up some 'alias' paths in `jest.config.js` but for whatever reason, I get errors in the form:

```js
Test suite failed to run

    src/__tests__/app.test.tsx:3:40 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '@/render/index'.
```

where I am trying to import like

```js
import { render, fireEvent, act } from '@/render/index';
```

This should be resolving to `/src/testUtils/render/index` as per my `jest.config.js` file:

```js
// jest.config.js
// eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-var-requires
const { defaults } = require('jest-config');
const ignores = [
    '[/\\\\]node_modules[/\\\\].+\\.(ts|tsx|js|jsx|mjs)$',
    '/__tests__/helpers/',
    '__mocks__',
];
module.exports = {
    roots: ['<rootDir>/src'],
    preset: 'ts-jest',
    setupFiles: ['<rootDir>/src/testUtils/globals/index.ts'],
    setupFilesAfterEnv: ['<rootDir>/src/testUtils/jest.setup.ts'],
    moduleFileExtensions: [...defaults.moduleFileExtensions, 'ts', 'tsx'],
    moduleDirectories: ['src', 'src/testUtils/render/', 'node_modules', 'src/testUtils/globals/'],
    moduleNameMapper: {
        // Tell jest to look in the src/testUtils/render/ dir when we use @/
        '^@/render/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/src/testUtils/render/$1',
        '^@/globals/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/src/testUtils/globals/$1',
    },
    modulePaths: ['<rootDir>'],
    testMatch: ['<rootDir>/**/__tests__/**/*.test.+(ts|tsx)', '<rootDir>/**/*.test.ts'],
    testURL: 'http://localhost',
    transform: {
        '\\.(ts|js)x?$': 'ts-jest',
        '^.+\\.css$': '<rootDir>/config/jest/cssTransform.js',
        '^(?!.*\\.(mjs|css|json)$)': '<rootDir>/config/jest/fileTransform.js',
    },
    transformIgnorePatterns: [...ignores],
    coverageDirectory: '<rootDir>/src/testUtils/coverage',
    collectCoverageFrom: ['<rootDir>/**/*.{ts,tsx,mjs}', '<rootDir>/**/**/*.{ts,tsx,mjs}'],
    coveragePathIgnorePatterns: [
        ...ignores,
        '<rootDir>/testUtils/',
        '<rootDir>/src/serviceWorker.ts',
    ],
    collectCoverage: false,
    coverageThreshold: {
        global: {
            branches: 40,
            functions: 40,
            lines: 40,
            statements: 40,
        },
    },
    prettierPath: './node_modules/prettier',
    timers: 'fake',
    verbose: true,
    errorOnDeprecated: true,
    globals: {
        'ts-jest': {
            tsConfig: 'tsconfig.extend.json',
            diagnostics: true,
        },
    },
    extraGlobals: ['Math'],
    notify: true,
    watchPathIgnorePatterns: ['<rootDir>/src/serviceWorker.ts'],
    snapshotSerializers: ['jest-serializer-html'],
};
```

I've tried updating Jest to latest, and then to `25.5.4`, but nothing has changed anything. This used to work at some point in the past so I don't know what exactly to do to fix it. Would someone have any ideas?

**Tried updating `ts-jest` and `jest` both to 26.0.0. Still no luck.**

Comment: Did you ever solve this?